# Where else can the variable innodb_buffer_pool_size be accessed besides my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've installed MAMP and have the latest phpMyAdmin on my Mac. I do not have a `my.cnf` nor a `my.ini` file. Yes, I have enabled all invisible files.

I've heard the free version of MAMP doesn't let you, but that doesn't seem right. I know MAMPPro has a drop-down but I'm not buying that.

What else could the file be called?

EDIT: I used grep to search for innodb_buffer_pool_size within the entire MAMP folder and the only files that had that variable inside were assigning an array to it, not just a simple size. Just for more completeness on this question.

Comment: Any system variable can be accessed from a query or command line. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html

Comment: Thanks. I found this so I'm exploring.

Answer (score 40):

You can do the following:

MySQL 5.0+

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
```

MySQL 5.1+

```
SELECT variable_value FROM information_schema.global_variables
WHERE variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
```

In order to set it for MySQL, you must have a physically manifest `my.cnf` or `my.ini`

Add this to the config file

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
```

and restart mysql

You can try placing the `my.cnf` in `/etc` and restarting mysql

Please keep in mind that [**128M is the default value for innodb_buffer_pool_size in MySQL 5.5**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size). Once you get my.cnf in the correct place in the DB Server and restart mysql, things will be different.

Comment: anytime I add a 'my.cnf' file into the msyql directory, the server will not start. I've even just tried putting only that line in it, changing the ports to match MAMP settings etc. Seems like with the specific MAMP install, the 128meg limit was compiled/hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a configuration file for MySQL from MAMP then it would be located in /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/my.cnf.

If there is no configuration file then the default value of 8MB.

Comment: via phpMyAdmin says it is 128megs. Even at the command line and logged in as root, I get the message that it is 'read only.'